# can't tap on item in google autocomplete list on mobile

Tags: autocomplete, cordova

I'm making a mobile-app using Phonegap and HTML. Now I'm using the google maps/places autocomplete feature. The problem is: if I run it in my browser on my computer everything works fine and I choose a suggestion to use out of the autocomplete list - if I deploy it on my mobile I still get suggestions but I'm not able to tap one. It seems the "suggestion-overlay" is just ignored and I can tap on the page. Is there a possibility to put focus on the list of suggestions or something that way ? 
Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one with a solution? Z-index on the pac-container or pac-item is not working sadly.

Answer (score 53):

There is indeed a conflict with FastClick and PAC. I found that I needed to add the **needsclick** class to both the **pac-item** and all its children.

```
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('needsclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');
```

Comment: This solution uses a [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) feature; furthermore, it may cause performance problems.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I put that on my code, I see that the class needsclick was added to all objects, but the problem remain. Nothing happens when I tap

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Geezz... I LOVE YOU!

Answer (score 9):

There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/pull/347) on github, but this hasn't been merged yet.

However, you can simply use this [patched version](https://github.com/epegzz/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js) of fastclick.

The patch adds the `excludeNode` option which let's you exclude DOM nodes handled by fastclick via regex. This is how I used it to make google autocomplete work with fastclick:

```
FastClick.attach(document.body, {
  excludeNode: '^pac-'
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, I dont know why it is not getting much rating....

Answer (score 6):

This reply may be too late. But might be helpful for others.

I had the same issue and after debugging for hours, I found out this issue was because of adding "FastClick" library. After removing this, it worked as usual.

So for having fastClick and google suggestions, I have added this code in geo autocomplete

```
jQuery.fn.addGeoComplete = function(e){
    var input = this;
    $(input).attr("autocomplete" , "off");
    var id = input.attr("id");
    $(input).on("keypress", function(e){
        var input = this;
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.2555, -121.9245),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.2555, -121.9245));

        var options = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            mapkey: "xxx"
        };

        //Fix for fastclick issue
        var g_autocomplete = $("body > .pac-container").filter(":visible");
        g_autocomplete.bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
            $(".pac-item", this).addClass("needsclick");
        });
        //End of fix

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(id), options);
         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
             //Handle place selection
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: +1! Z-index solutions did not work for me. FastClick was the culprit in my case. Much appreciated! I have linked to this comment from my original question http://stackoverflow.com/a/17162343/1177832 for any others with this problem.

Comment: @saravanan Do you have non jquery solution?

Answer (score 6):

if you are using Framework 7, it has a custom implementation of FastClicks. Instead of the `needsclick` class, F7 has `no-fastclick`. The function below is how it is implemented in F7:

```
 function targetNeedsFastClick(el) {
   var $el = $(el);
   if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && el.type === 'file') return false;
   if ($el.hasClass('no-fastclick') || $el.parents('.no-fastclick').length > 0) return false;
   return true;
 }
```

So as suggested in other comments, you will only have to add the `.no-fastclick` class to `.pac-item` and in all its children

Comment: Thank you so much   i fixed like this
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('no-fastclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');

Comment: You deserve a tons of like. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,
I realized what the problem was that probably the focusout event of pac-container happens before the tap event of the pac-item (only in phonegap built-in browser).

The only way I could solve this, is to add padding-bottom to the input when it is focused and change the top attribute of the pac-container, so that the pac-container resides within the borders of the input.

Therefore when user clicks on item in list the focusout event is not fired.

It's dirty, but it works

Comment: Adam, can you explain better how your solution works?

Answer (score 0):

worked perfectly for me :

```
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('needsclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');
```

Configuration: Cordova / iOS iphone 5