# Google Places Autocomplete issue on iOS7 (webview)

Tags: ios7, autocomplete, google-places-api, keyboard-events

I currently have an issue implementing a simple Google Places Autocomplete input in a webview.

My issue seems to be related to a bug in ios7 where the blur event is triggered before the place_changed has been fired, thus the input field doesn't take the chosen value.

Here is the code (part of an AngularJS directive):

```
  var newAutocomplete = function () {
                scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], opts);

                google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        var place = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                        if (!place || !place.geometry) {
                            return;
                        }

                        scope.location = {
                            coords: {
                                lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                                lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
                            },
                            address: element.val()
                        };
                    });
                });
            };
```

Any idea how to handle this? Delaying the onBlur event?

Thanks in advance.

[SELF-ANSWERED]

I just found out the problem was related to the use of the FastClick library.

This is what needs to be added in the page to make it work:

```
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('needsclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');
```

Thanks to [can't tap on item in google autocomplete list on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972080/cant-tap-on-item-in-google-autocomplete-list-on-mobile/16932543#16932543) for the solution!

Comment: I'm not using JQuery, and it seems like `DOMNodeInserted ` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent#Browser_compatibility any suggestion