# angular: google autocomplete works on pc, but tapping on mobile doesn't load the suggestion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am actually having the same issue as:

[can't tap on item in google autocomplete list on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972080/cant-tap-on-item-in-google-autocomplete-list-on-mobile)

In short: I tap on google's autocomplete suggestion, and it does not work on mobile, while it works just fine on PC.

BUT: I am not using cordova, just plain angular with nodejs and responsiveness. I indeed HAD FastClick enabled, but disabling didn't solve the problem....

EDIT: Here's my code for completeness:
Markup (jade):

```
div
  input(type="text" id="fulladdress" name="fulladdress" ng-model="location" class="form-control text-field" placeholder="Start typing...")
```

and in the view:

```
form.row(ng-show="vm.isLogged" name="vm.form")
  h2.order-title Delivery address
  label(for="address") Address
  google-places(location="vm.address")
```

js:

```
'use strict';

GooglePlacesDirective.$inject = ['$animate', 'Zipcode'];

function GooglePlacesDirective($animate, Zipcode) {
    return {
        scope: {location:'='},
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: require('./google-places.html'),
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element) {
        scope.codeNotServed = false;
        var options = {
          componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#fulladdress")[0], options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            scope.codeNotServed = false;
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var parts = place.address_components;
            //do things with the parts; I've also tried doing nothing with the parts, but it didn't work either
         });
    }
}

module.exports = GooglePlacesDirective;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - commenting out not only the code:

```
/*
if ('addEventListener' in document) {
    console.log("Attaching FastClick event listener");
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }, false);
}
*/
```

but also the actual LOADING of the library:

```
<!--
<script src="/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
-->
```

seems to have solved the problem!